# Source of graph data to play with

Tags: algorithm, graph

Where I can find some graph data to applying different graph analyzing tools? I am looking for > 1M nodes and more than > 10 M edges.

Comment: Can you be more specific? Does it need to be planar? Does it need to be connected? Does it need to be directed? Why can you not generate graphs at random?

Answer (score 4):

[Stanford Snap Data](http://snap.stanford.edu/data/)

Specifically, cit-Patents should be useful.

Comment: It is OT but maybe you know some machine learning data as well?

Comment: Sorry, I don't know off hand.

Comment: @Sławosz: You can check http://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/ for that.

Answer (score 1):

if you use python, networkx can generate a lot of common graphs for you, with arbitrary sizes. see http://networkx.github.io/documentation/latest/reference/generators.html